# task :after_update_code is deprecated ... whats the new way of writing this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

So I'm using this as my current after_update

```
task :after_update_code, :roles => :app do
    do_something
end
```

But on deploy I get this error message

```
 before_ and after_ is deprecated, please see the new before() and after() methods
```

I took a look and tried writing this

```
after :update_code, :roles => app do
    do_something
end
```

but Capistrano just ignored it.
What is the right way to update this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice how 'see' isn't 'use'. (Guh. It's always hard to find capistrano documentation.)
https://github.com/leehambley/capistrano-handbook/blob/master/index.markdown
 http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/5/11/capistrano-2-0-preview-2

```
after 'deploy:update_code' do
 #etc
end
```

Looks like you have to fully qualify the name of the task.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the documentation, you're right, its amazingly hard to find